# htaccess - Rewrite PHP $_GET only in root

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change the $_GET['p'] variable in my url to it's own, but without the ?=.

Example:
www.example.com/?p=about to www.example.com/about

The problem is that my bit of htaccess code also reacts to subfolders aswell.

If I want to access my images folder as an example, I get:
www.example.com/images/?p=images

How do I make sure my .htaccess ignores any subfolder?

This is the .htaccess I'm currently using

    `RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    # Rewrite page include

    #RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?p=$1`

Sorry for my bad explaination.

-Banana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

# ignore existing files (only apply to non-file)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#ignore folders (only apply to non-folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# here you might also want to exclude some specific locations...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(images|css|js)/

# finally, apply the rule...
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

All the `RewriteCond` conditions are chained (only if all of them pass, then the rule is applied).